# Negative numbers in fixed point format

Tags: binary, fixed-point

If I have a number `-1.101001_2 * 2^(-4)`, which is `-0.1025390625` in decimal, what is the correct fixed-point representation for this number?

From what I have understood about fixed-point, this means it should be signed, so I thought that this would give a word length of 12 with a fraction length of 10, i.e.:

```
1   0    0001101001
(s)        (frac)
--- (word)-------
```

but this doesn't seem to be correct, as `100001101001` with word length of 12 and fraction length of 10 (1 signed bit) gives `-1.8975` instead.

Did I make a mistake in the interpretation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are confusing the sign-magnitude and two's-complement representations for signed values. Fixed-point numbers are treated as integers so if you want to have signed fixed-point values they will almost certainly use a two's-complement representation.

If your real value is -0.1025390625 and you have 10 fractional bits then the corresponding fixed-point value is
-0.1025390625 * 2<sup>10</sup> = -105

The proper 12-bit two's-complement representation of -105 is 1111 1001 0111